# Navigate to new page after barcode scanning without going back to original page

Tags: flutter

Using this: https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_barcode_reader

Tha page:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // Skipped all boilerplates
        child: new MaterialButton(
            onPressed: scan, 
            child: new Text("Scan")
        ),
    }

    Future scan() async {
        String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/scanResult');
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it shows the HomePage. Then when I clicked on the button, it shows the barcode scanning page. When it finished scanning, it'll go back to HomePage again briefly, and only after that it will navigate to /scanResult page.

How do I navigate directly to /scanResult page without the scanning page redirecting me to the HomePage?

FWIW, the BarcodeScanner.scan() calls an Activity on Android (I think), so am I limited by the library? I've no idea, never touched native Android development, I'm just being suspicious.

GIF explains this better:

[image]

If you noticed, right after the scanning, before it navigates to next page, it shows the main page very briefly.

Answer (score 0):

I think using **popAndPushNamed** might solve your issue it will first pop your scan page before redirecting you to your empty page.